# Find ASCII of each character of a string in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My requirement is to find if the ASCII character is outside the range of 32 to 126 and if so, I need to replace that character with !.
For example;  if the string name is Hello and let us assume e's ASCII is outside the range of 32 to 126, I replace it with ! as H!llo.

I am fairly new to Snowflake and tried looking at the snowflake documents.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways you can accomplish this, [regular expression functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp) are often used for text search and replacement.

Replace all characters not in range of 32 (\x20) - 126 (~)

`select regexp_replace('Héllo', '[^\x20-~]','!') as value`

| value |
| --- |
| H!llo |